# How to remove 15 mins data from a single day hour using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataset `df` is `minute` based and looks like this:

```
Time                    Open
2017-01-03 07:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 07:01:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 07:02:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 07:03:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 07:04:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 07:05:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 07:06:00     5.2475
.....
```

For each day, I want to start at `7:15:00` and not `7:00:00`

**What did I do?**

I tried to remove the first 15 `rows` but then I would need to do it for each `day` which would be a lot of repeated work.

How can I identify a `day` and then for every `7 AM`, start at `7:15:00` using Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `dt` accessor:

```
from datetime import time
df[df['Time'].dt.time >= time(7, 15)]
```